Why RXJS filter operator not working here?
I have a switchMap that I need to check for additional condition before I go into subscribe, in this I want to pick out the studyId that matches with the provided studyId I got:
     this.studyIdObs$.pipe(
        switchMap((studyData) => {
          if (studyData.studyId) {
            ...
            return this._autocompleteFilterService.getFilteredStudyIdList(studyData.studyId).pipe(
              filter(list => list.studyId === studyData.studyId)
            );
          }
          return of(studyData);
        }),
      ).subscribe(() => ...)

However I got an error inside the filter which says Property 'studyId' does not exist on type 'StudyIdDTO[]' not sure why because filter should work on a list and getFilteredStudyIdList would return an Observable<Array< StudyIdDTO>>
As checking on official doc, there is a similar use case that works:
//emit (1,2,3,4,5)
const source = from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
//filter out non-even numbers
const example = source.pipe(filter(num => num % 2 === 0));


Filter is for filtering out observables from the stream, but here you need to filter an array so use a map instead.
If the api call returns only the data of study id, why do you even need to filter?
 this.studyIdObs$.pipe(
    switchMap((studyData) => {
      if (studyData.studyId) {
        ...
        return this._autocompleteFilterService.getFilteredStudyIdList(studyData.studyId).pipe(
          map(list => list.filter((item:any) => item.studyId === studyData.studyId))
        );
      }
      return of(studyData);
    }),
  ).subscribe(() => ...)


I see the issue in your code. The problem is that getFilteredStudyIdList returns an Observable array of StudyIdDTO objects, but you're trying to access a studyId property directly on the array in the filter operator.
To fix this, you need to use map to transform the array into a single item that matches the studyId, or use find to locate the matching item in the array. Here's how you can modify your code:
this.studyIdObs$.pipe(
  switchMap((studyData) => {
    if (studyData.studyId) {
      return this._autocompleteFilterService.getFilteredStudyIdList(studyData.studyId).pipe(
        map(list => list.find(item => item.studyId === studyData.studyId))
      );
    }
    return of(studyData);
  }),
).subscribe(() => ...)

This approach will return the matching StudyIdDTO object if found, or undefined if not found.
If you want to ensure that you only proceed with the subscription when a matching item is found, you can add a filter after the map:
this.studyIdObs$.pipe(
  switchMap((studyData) => {
    if (studyData.studyId) {
      return this._autocompleteFilterService.getFilteredStudyIdList(studyData.studyId).pipe(
        map(list => list.find(item => item.studyId === studyData.studyId)),
        filter(item => item !== undefined)
      );
    }
    return of(studyData);
  }),
).subscribe(() => ...)

This will ensure that the subscription only occurs when a matching StudyIdDTO is found in the list.
The example from the official documentation works because it operates on a simple array of numbers, not an observable array of objects. In your case, you need to handle the array structure returned using your service method.
Would you like me to explain or break down this code further?

this.studyIdObs$.pipe(
  switchMap((studyData) => {
    if (studyData.studyId) {
      return this._autocompleteFilterService.getFilteredStudyIdList(studyData.studyId).pipe(
        // Use map to transform the list to find the item that matches the studyId
        map(list => list.find(item => item.studyId === studyData.studyId)),
        // Filter out any undefined values (when no matching item is found)
        filter(matchingItem => !!matchingItem)
      );
    }
    return of(studyData);
  }),
).subscribe((matchingItem) => {
  // Handle the matching item
  console.log(matchingItem);
});

This approach ensures that you correctly filter the observable stream to only include items that match your criteria before they are emitted to the subscribe block.
